# Unload backbone view and unregister events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a simple editor where you can click on an element and load a script template with a simple input and when I type I wish to update to DOM element. The problem is, if I click on the heading, then the intro and start typing the text is updated for both the heading and the intro. How can I "unload" the view and only let one view live?

```js
$(function() {
  window.Brick = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    render: function() {
      this.$el.mouseenter(function() {
        $(this)
          .css('outline', 'solid #467ace 1px')
          .css('outline-offset', '-1px')
          .css('cursor', 'pointer');
      }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this)
          .css('outline', 'none')
          .css('cursor', 'default');
      });
    },
    events: {
      "click": "openEditor"
    },
    openEditor: function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      console.log('load editor');

      var self = this;

      self.editorView = new MyView({
        el: $('#editor-panel'),
        editorName: self.$el.attr('data-brick-name'),
        editor: self.$el
      });
    }
  });

  window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    editorName: null,
    editor: null,
    initialize: function(options) {
      _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "editorName"));
      _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "editor"));
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      var self = this;
      // Compile the template using underscore
      var template = _.template($('#' + self.editorName).html());
      // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
      this.$el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
      'keyup :input': 'logKey'
    },
    logKey: function(e) {
      console.log($(this.editor).text());
      $(this.editor).text($(e.currentTarget).val());
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('[data-editable="true"]').each(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var self = $(this);
    var brick = new Brick({
      el: self
    }).render();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>



<h1 data-editable="true" data-brick-name="heading">Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p data-editable="true" data-brick-name="intro">Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet...</p>

<div id="editor-panel">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="heading">
  <label for="Heading">Rubrik</label>
  <input name="Heading" type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" />
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="intro">
  <label for="Intro">Intro</label>
  <textarea name="Intro">Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet...</textarea>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `undelegateEvents`.  From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents):

> undelegateEvents;
>   Removes all of the view's delegated events. Useful if you want to disable or remove a view from the DOM temporarily.

Calling that on the Header view will prevent it from reacting to the keyboard events while they are being processed by the other input. You can reattach event listeners via `delegateEvents`.